# Excel shortcut to go back to previous cell (last position)

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, shortcuts

There is a cool shortcut to go to a precedent cell:  ctrl+[
This takes you to the source of your data in a cell that is linked from another worksheet for example.

I'm trying to find a shortcut that will take me back to the original cell that I was viewing. Doesn't seem to exist.   Anyone?

Answer (score 15):

Either of the following sets of keystrokes will take you back to the original cell:

- F5, Enter
- Ctrl+G, Enter

F5 and Ctrl+G are shortcuts to bring up the "Go To" dialogue box. The dialogue box will be pre-populated with the address of the original cell, and you can press Enter to go there.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work in Excel for Mac

Comment: @yannick1976 You're probably right. I was only talking about the Windows version - don't have a Mac and my searching about it just now didn't give an answer one way or the other.

Answer (score 1):

I think <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd> works, but only if you have the target cell still selected and it will select **all** dependants of that cell, not just the one you got there from.

Comment: Good tip! However, this only appears to work as long as the dependent cell is on the same worksheet.

Answer (score 1):

You could make a macro to do this.

First you would want to create a macro that runs when "ctrl+[" is run that remembers your current worksheet and cell, and then runs the usual command that jumps you to the source (to find this out, try recording a macro when you push the ctrl+[ and see what command is used).  Now that you're position is saved, you can create a second macro with hotkey of your choosing that will grab the saved worksheet and position and jump to that spot.

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>F5</kbd>

In the new window, click `Special`.

From here, click on Last `Cell` and then press `enter`.

Or, if you want keyboard then it's <kbd>F5</kbd> <kbd>ALT</kbd>+ <kbd>S</kbd> and then another
 <kbd>S</kbd> and then <kbd>Enter</kbd>

The above could easily be assigned to a keyboard mapping tool like AUTOHOTKEY so it would be a single instruction.

Comment: Just to save anyone else trying this - it takes you to the final (last) cell of the used range, not the cell that you were previously in.