# how to cancel the focus change of cells in excel 2007?

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-excel-2007

When I move the cursor in Excel 2007 from cell A1 to cell A2, so that cell A2 is highlighted instead of A1, sometimes I press the <kbd>tab</kbd> key too quickly, so I try to go back and highlight A1 again.

I tried <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>, however this doesn't work, is it true it won't work in 2007? I thought every move in Excel can be cancelled by using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Excel shortcut to go back to previous cell (last position)](http://superuser.com/questions/178351/excel-shortcut-to-go-back-to-previous-cell-last-position) - See my answer on this post, I think it's exactly what you want.

Comment: try using the Enter key

Comment: @Dave in fact i am not talking about quotes and dependants, i just talk about any cell in general, when i go from one to another, may it be empty or not.

Comment: @Firee that won't work...that only go to one cell down.

Comment: @huiwang, did you try my answer in the other post and you're saying it doesn't work?

Comment: @Dave right, it doesn't fit, i am not talking about formula, the other post is about formula and dependents.

Comment: When you say "move" do you mean move the cursor or move the contents of a cell?

Comment: @Dave I mean move the cursor

Comment: So, you move the cursor by using the arrow key. Let's assume it was in A1, and you moved it to A10. Do you want it to return to A1 or A9?

Comment: @Dave  ok follow your example, i moved it by arrow key or mouse from A1 to A10, and then i want to return to A1

Comment: After you make the move,  Press F5. A new window appears. click Special. From here, click on Last Cell and then press enter. What happens?

Comment: @Dave it always go to the same cell.... i think maybe the cell that i last saved, but that's not what i need, i need to go the very last cell i just moved from, no matter saved or not.  And i think my points get deducted due to the hallucination that i asked the same question as someone else b4, tks to your contribution to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Undo (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>) only applies to changes. Individual navigation keystrokes (<kbd>up</kbd>, <kbd>down</kbd>, <kbd>left</kbd>, <kbd>right</kbd>, <kbd>tab</kbd> etc) are not considered changes so aren't tracked by Excel (in any version AFAIK).

However, there are a couple of things you can do to speed up your keyboard navigation beyond the basic <kbd>up</kbd>, <kbd>down</kbd>, <kbd>left</kbd>, <kbd>right</kbd>, <kbd>PageUp</kbd>, <kbd>PageDown</kbd>, etc. Here are some suggestions:

1. The <kbd>Home</kbd> key you will jump to column 1 in the current row (assuming no columns are hidden), or if you have freeze panes in operation, it will jump to the left most column in the current pane.
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd> will take you to cell A1, or if you have panes frozen to the upper-left most cell in the active pane.
3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> will take you to the lowest-right cell used on the worksheet.
4. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> (or <kbd>up</kbd>, <kbd>down</kbd>, <kbd>right</kbd>) will take you to the edge cell in the currently selected range. eg if you have data in cells B2:D4 and you're in cell C4, hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> will take you to C2.
5. You're aware that using <kbd>Tab</kbd> will move you one cell to the right. However, if you press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> you will move one cell to the left.
6. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> brings up the `Go To` dialog box. Type in whatever cell reference you want to jump back to and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
7. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PageUp</kbd> is equivalent to "Page Left", <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PageDown</kbd> works as "Page Right".

If none of these are any use, you'd have to write some VBA to log your navigation keystrokes and assign a keyboard shortcut that returns you to the most recently used "significant" keystroke. That's overkill though frankly, the keyboard you used to overshoot your destination can take you back pretty quickly.

**See also:** [A complete list of Excel keyboard shortcuts for Excel 2007](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/excel-shortcut-and-function-keys-HP010073848.aspx).

Comment: you are the first one that got my meaning, thank god. Here you confirmed my suspicion as to whether the excel will 'ctrl+z) position moves, such as tab, arrow and mouse click. By the way if i use mouse click to set focus on another cell, excel can also not 'ctrl+z' it right?

Comment: Ctrl+z will ignore all position moves, including tab, arrow, page up, page down etc. Even if you click another cell with your mouse, Excel will pay that no attention. Ctrl+z only allows you to undo changes to the worksheet (eg changing a value, format or formula). Even turning freeze panes on and off gets ignored by undo, because it's not a change to the worksheet itself.

Comment: that's very helpful thank you! Just to confirm, ctrl+z won't do the cancel work, will there be any other shortcut to do the position or other non sheet changes?

Comment: Unfortunately no, Excel can't do this.

Comment: If this has answered your question would you mind ticking this to accept the answer?

Comment: sure, it's my pleasure

Answer (score 0):

If you accidentally overwrite the contents of a cell, pressing <kbd>ESC</kbd> will restore the original contents of the cell.

Comment: it's not overwriting, just shifting the focus ...

Comment: @dave I tried the answer in the other post and it won't work...coz it's not relevant to my question.